# How to access ID from the Python code file of an MDBoxLayout defined inside the Screen in KV file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm making a KivyMD app with 2 screens: MainScreen and DataScreen. The question relates to the DataScreen. I've divided the DataScreen inside the KV file into DataScreenTopBar and DataScreenBody, and both these components of the DataScreen are MDBoxLayouts. I want to access the ID of the DataScreenBody because I want to populate this component with data pulled from a database from inside the python file.

**However, when I try to access the ID of the DataScreenBody I get an empty dictionary when I try to print it**. I've tried all kinds of methods but I keep getting an empty dictionary. I also tried it with Clock.schedule_once, but that too gives an empty dictionary.

The code inside the Python file is given below:

```
class GameShotApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Game Shot"
        self.icon  = "./icon/favicon.png"
        return WindowManager()

class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    def btnClick(self):
        print("Btn Click")

class DataScreen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Here A:")
        print(self.ids)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.get_id)
        
    def get_id(self, dt):
        print("\nHere B:")
        print(self.ids)
        print(self.manager.get_screen("data_screen").ids)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

GameShotApp().run()
```

As you can see, I've tried these two different ways, in addition to others that I've not shown in the code, of accessing the ID's but I keep getting an empty dictionary. The screenshot of the output in the console is given below. The print statements' output in the picture is highlighted in yellow. Also, when I try to access the ID directly like this:
**self.ids.data_screen**

I get the following error: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

[image: Print Statement Output that shows empty ID dictionary]

The code in the KV file is given below. I've not posted all of the kv code of the MainScreen  class because it would make the question too long, and because the question is related to the DataScreen class. Please, note that all the code related to the DataScreen class both in the .py file and the .kv files is given in this question; there's no piece of code related to the DataScreen class that I've omitted.

```
<WindowManager>

<WindowManager>:
    MainScreen:
        name: "main_screen"
    DataScreen:
        name: "data_screen"

<MainScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: rgba("#F0F5F0") # White
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MainScreenTopBar:
        MainScreenBody:

<DataScreen>:
    id: data_screen
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: rgba("#F0F5F0") # White
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        DataScreenTopBar:
        DataScreenBody:

<DataScreenTopBar@MDBoxLayout>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    size_hint: 1, 0.125
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: rgba("#049D81") # Green 2
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    AnchorLayout:
        size_hint: 0.03, 1 
        TopBarIconBtn:
            icon: "./icon/prev_screen.png"
            tooltip_text: "Go Back"
            tooltip_bg_color: rgba("#F0F5F0")
            tooltip_text_color: rgba("#049D81")
            on_press: 
                print("Go to prev screen")
                app.root.current = "main_screen"
                app.root.transition.direction = "right"
    MDBoxLayout:
        size_hint: 0.51, 1 
        TopBarLabel:
            text: "Game Shot"
            halign: "right"
            color: rgba("#F0F5F0") # White
    MDBoxLayout:
        size_hint: 0.46, 1 

<DataScreenBody@MDBoxLayout>:
    id : data_screen_body
    orientation: "horizontal"
    size_hint: 1, 0.875
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: rgba("#F0F5F0") # White
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

The components used in the KV code such as TopBarLabel & TopBarIconBtn are defined in the same KV file, but before DataScreen class definition in the KV file.

As you can see, I've given both the DataScreen and DataScreenBody id's but when I try to access either or both of them, I get an empty dictionary in the console when I try to print it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataScreen` class will never have any `ids`. The `ids` are only added for children of the root object of the `kv` rule that contains them, and those `ids` must be defined explicitly in that rule. Your `DataScreen` rule contains just one `id`, but that `id` is for the `DataScreen` itself, so no `id` is added to the dict for that `id`.

So, you probably want to add an `id` in the `DataScreen` rule, like this:

```
<DataScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: rgba("#F0F5F0") # White
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    MDBoxLayout:
        id: mdboxlayout
        orientation: "vertical"
        DataScreenTopBar:
        DataScreenBody:
```

Note that the kivy use of the term `root object` is not clearly defined. There can be at most one `root` widget in a `kv` file, but every rule has a `root` object.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. I posted the same question on Kivy's subreddit on reddit and a commenter there told me something similar along the lines of your answer. He asked me to add id's directly to the DataScreenTopBar and DataScreenBody, and it worked when I did that. Thanks for your answer; you've clarified things further.